# Demos la opción de cancelar la recompensa y recuperar parte de la reputación

Tags: característica-nueva, recompensas

Mi idea es que den la opcion de cancelar recompensa pero con tres condiciones:

Se podrá cancelar después de 3 días en que se inició la recompensa si:

1. Que la pregunta no tiene respuestas o el usuario haya encontrado una solución.
2. De cumplir con el punto 1, se debera compartir la solución.
3. Si se cancela antes de los 7 días, se le descontara el 20% del valor de la recompensa. Ejemplo: si la recompensa es de `+100`, al cancelar el usuario recupera solo `+80`.

Comment: El sistema de recompensas, como muchas cosas, es conjunto con toda la red. Esto deberia proponerse para toda la red. Si queres, podes hacerlo en ingles en meta.se. Dudo que cambien el sistema.

Comment: @gbianchi porque dudas? porque esa actitud? que pasa, no se te ocurrio a ti la idea? Es muy bueno lo que dice previant, tendrias que ser mejor persona y apoyarlo.

Comment: No tengo ninguna actitud. Hay cosas que funcionan globalmente para toda la red. No dudo de esta propuesta, ni la apruebo ni la desapruebo. Lo que estoy diciendo es que hay cambios que son dificiles de hacer porque impactan no solo a este sitio, si no a toda la red SE.

Comment: PAra mas informacion: esta pidiendo que se cambie un sistema que esta desde los inicios del sitio, y es asi por defecto, para provocar que una pregunta sea mas visible. Si cancela la oferta, entonces esta haciendo trampa, porque esa pregunta fue visible por mas tiempo. Mas alla de eso, justamente el sistema es asi: Can I cancel my bounty?

No. Once you start a bounty, you cannot cancel it.

If you feel there are exceptional circumstances, flag the question for moderator attention to explain the situation. (en [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/141717))

Comment: Y en [nuestra ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) dice expresamente: La reputación que utilizas para la recompensa es inmediata e irreversiblemente descontada de tu reputación. Por eso digo que es dificil, no que no lo pueda proponer. Adelante con eso!

Comment: Como idea está bien, pero para convertirse en una propuesta falta agregar la motivación o beneficios para la comunidad de que esto se lleve a cabo y sería aún más completa si se indicara cuáles son los problemas o dolencias que causan las reglas actuales.

Answer (score 6):

Estoy en desacuerdo con la propuesta.

Cuando ofreces una recompensa estás "pagando" por recibir atención en una pregunta determinada. Tengamos en cuenta que la pregunta para a ser "una de muchas" a ser "una de las pocas que aparece en la sección de destacadas". Invertir apenas 50 o 100 puntos de reputación en ello ya lo vale.

Siguiendo el símil de "pagar", es como si yo soy un directivo de una empresa y pongo publicidad en la televisión. Como no me llegan ventas, pido a la televisión que me devuelva el dinero. No tendría mucho sentido porque estaría apuntando a una causa tangencial y probablemente lo que habría que repensar es el anuncio. Volviendo a nuestro caso, si una recompensa no genera el resultado que esperábamos lo que habrá que pensar es si antes de ofrecerlo hemos analizado cosas como:

- ¿Estaba la pregunta lo suficientemente bien formulada para que la gente pudiera animarse a contestarla?
- ¿He hecho lo posible para que la gente se anime a contestarla?
- ¿Realmente en el sitio hay nicho de usuarios con conocimiento suficiente de la tecnología para contestarla?

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. El sistema de recompensas de SE está suficientemente probado y discutido (una simple búsqueda de [bounty] en el meta de StackOverflow da numerosos resultados), y creo que tiene poco margen de mejora.

Comment: Qué gracia que siempre me casquen un negativo, sea lo que sea lo que publique. Precioso todo.

Comment: *haters gonna hate*

Comment: en un principio tenia cierto apoyo antes esa propuesta de recuperar la recompensa, pero la analizarlo detenidamente tu respuesta es muy cierto, por algo existe la forma correcta de como preguntar.